# CiviCRM on WordPress crashes when I select ZMK as default currency

Tags: wordpress, currency

A clean install of CiviCRM on Wordpress crashes whenever I select ZMK as default currency. My installation details are:

> WordPress version 5.9.2
> Current theme: Twenty Twenty-Two (version 1.1)
> Current plugin: CiviCRM (version 5.47.2)
> PHP version 8.0.16

````
=============
An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 19 of the file /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/brick/money/src/Exception/UnknownCurrencyException.php. Error message: Uncaught Brick\Money\Exception\UnknownCurrencyException: Unknown currency code: ZMK in /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/brick/money/src/Exception/UnknownCurrencyException.php:19
Stack trace:
#0 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/brick/money/src/ISOCurrencyProvider.php(120): Brick\Money\Exception\UnknownCurrencyException::unknownCurrency()
#1 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/brick/money/src/Currency.php(91): Brick\Money\ISOCurrencyProvider->getCurrency()
#2 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/brick/money/src/Money.php(189): Brick\Money\Currency::of()
#3 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Money.php(209): Brick\Money\Money::of()
#4 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Money.php(88): CRM_Utils_Money::formatUSLocaleNumericRounded()
#5 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources/Common.php(219): CRM_Utils_Money::format()
#6 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources/Common.php(128): CRM_Core_Resources_Common::coreResourceList()
#7 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/CachedCiviContainer.a02b080bd0d8fdf7053d123f1aecc5d2.php(807): CRM_Core_Resources_Common::createFullBundle()
#8 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Container.php(306): CachedCiviContainer->getBundle_CoreResourcesService()
#9 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi.php(174): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get()
#10 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php(214): Civi::service()
#11 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php(382): CRM_Core_Resources->addBundle()
#12 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1087): CRM_Core_Resources->addCoreResources()
#13 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.admin.php(761): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->add_core_resources()
#14 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Admin->admin_page_load()
#15 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#16 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-includes/plugin.php(474): WP_Hook->do_action()
#17 /home/monkey/public_html/civic/wp-admin/admin.php(237): do_action()
#18 {main}
  thrown```

After this, I can't do anything else under the CiviCRM menu.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this seems like a bug. Can you make a ticket at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/-/issues/new ?

Looks like it changed to ZMW in 2013.

If you have access to the mysql database you can get your site back by doing `UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value='s:3:"USD";' WHERE name='defaultCurrency';`

Comment: Thanks Demerit! That worked for me. I have reported the issue accordingly.